# Need to add percentages to my barplot in ggplot2 but the percentages are jumping to the bottom instead of the top

Tags: r, ggplot2

Mortified this code from another post; everything it's doing is right but I need the percentages to sit ontop of the bars not below. Any ideas?

```
structure(list(Year = c(2020L, 2021L, 2022L, NA), number = c(55L, 
81L, 187L, 3L), pct = c(0.168711656441718, 0.248466257668712, 
0.573619631901841, 0.00920245398773006)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))


ggplot(data = year_table, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = number)) +
  geom_col(fill= "darkslategray3") + theme_economist() +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Applicants based on Class Year") +
  geom_text(data=year_table, aes(label=paste0(round(pct*100,1),"%"),
                               y=pct+0.012), size=4)
```

Comment: Your y scale for the plot is based on `number`.  This is an integer varible with a max of 187.  You then use `pct` for the y scale for adding the text, which are tiny numbers compared to `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use `number` for the `y` of your text instead of `pct`.
I added `vjust = -.5` to make the text appear on the text line above the bar.

```
library(ggplot2); library(ggthemes)
ggplot(data = year_table, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = number)) +
  geom_col(fill= "darkslategray3") + theme_economist() +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Applicants based on Class Year") +
  geom_text(data=year_table, aes(label=paste0(round(pct*100,1),"%"),
                                 y=number), size=4, vjust = -.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative:

```
ggplot(data = year_table, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = number)) +
  geom_col(fill= "darkslategray3") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = scales::percent(pct)), size=4, vjust = 0, nudge_y = 2
  )+
  labs(title = "Distribution of Applicants based on Class Year") +
  ggthemes::theme_economist()
```

You can use `scales::percent` and `scales` is a `ggplot2` dependency so it comes along for the install ride, then you can use `vjust = 0` with a `nudge_y` to re-adjust the text.

You also don't need to re-specify the `data`.